# Qt -" \n" doesn't work, but std::endl does?

Tags: c++, qt, std, qtcore

I have a rather strange problem that I've never encountered before and I have no idea what is causing it. I'm working in Qt 4.7, and I have a lot of things in my project that print to the terminal. These prints are all triggered by one button press. However, when I press the button, they don't all print. Instead, all the print statements that end with `<< std::endl;` will print, but the first one that ends with `"random text...\n";` won't, and none of the ones after that will either regardless of which style they use. If I hit the button again to run the entire thing again, it will *then* print the remaining statements, followed by the same initial output as last time. I could just make them all std::endl, but there's a *lot* of them, so I'd really rather not. I've never seen anything like this before, does anyone have any advice for how to fix it? Thanks!

**EDIT**: As per request, this is the syntax (assuming there's a button call mybutton on the UI)

`void on_mybutton_pressed()

{

  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;

std::cout << "B" << std::endl;

std::cout << "C\n";

}`

Output after first time button is pressed:


`A

B`

Output after second press:


`C

A

B`

Comment: please let see your code

Comment: @dare I'll add an example of the syntax

Comment: @Pavel Windows, but I've used \n countless time in Qt before with no problem whatsoever, I've been working in it for months and this is the first time it's ever given me a problem.

Comment: @Pavel Strakhov: That's false. In a text output stream (like `std::cout`) `\n` is automatically translated into whatever is OK for the target platform. E.g. on Windows it will automatically be converted to `\r\n` sequence.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Uhm, it depends on your compiler. The C and C++ standards [don't require `\n` to be translated to either CR or LF (or CR+LF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages).

Comment: @JBL For a text output stream, the `'\n'` character (whatever is it) is translated to an end-of-line representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable unit buffering for `cout` at the beginning of your program if you really want to:

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf;
```

This will flush the buffer after *every* output operation.

In your situation, I'd consider this a bit of a hack rather than a solution though. There are performance penalties associated with flushing (though they do not matter if you don't print at high frequencies).

Comment: s/"enable"/"disable"?

Comment: I don't think so? Afaik, "unit buffering" refers to only *one* 'unit' being buffered, i.e. automatic flushing after every `<<`.

Answer (score 2):

Character output is buffered. The buffer is flushed when it gets full, but often for a terminal you don't want to wait for that; `std::endl` is special in that it causes the buffer to be flushed immediately.

Comment: Shouldn't that only happen though if there's a large amount already printed out with the buffer? It seems like it should only really be an issue when the buffer's already been used to print a lot of characters, but if I put \n into the first print statement it will behave the same as if I put it in the 100th

Comment: @thnkwthprtls I don't quite understand your question. `\n` doesn't force the buffer to be written to the device, but `std::endl` does, and the amount of output doesn't change that at all.